# How set Alternate Cell Color in a Grid

Tags: android

How set alternate cell Color in a grid ?
I've found a lot of questions/tutorials
about how to set row colors but nothing
about cells' color.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A step forward and it works

```
public class ListViewA extends Activity {
GridView MyGrid;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MyGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    MyGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context MyContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context _MyContext) {
        MyContext = _MyContext;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 9;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            view = li.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        }

        if (position % 2 == 0)
            view.setBackgroundColor(0x30FF0000);
        else
            view.setBackgroundColor(0x300000FF);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: //main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:columnWidth="30dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#ffffff"
/>

Answer (score 2):

If you got a lot of examples for listView, why not just use getView method, as getView method is used for adapter and adapter is used in both views, list and grid. just set background of view according to the position of view in adapterview.

```
protected void getView(AdapterView<> adapterView, View convertView, int position, long id)
{

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view =inflater.inflate(yourlayout.xml, null);

    if(position%2==0)
        view.setBackgroundColor(color1);
    else
        view.setBackgroundColor(color2);
     return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm new at android so if you give me more hint. Steps 1) get the grid from within the my Activity GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview); what's the step 2

Comment: I'm pleased if you show me the way step by step without the code.

Comment: in your adapter of grid view override method getView

Comment: Sorry to bother you but it's just a little time I'm learning android stuff so where should I set up getView (in a Adpater or directly in the Activity) be patience :)

Comment: If you can write your adapter code, I can edit your code to implement this.

Comment: Thanks jitendra for your patience. I should find all the logic around the android code.I don't know the class involved ..... I tried with

Comment: import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

Comment: public class SpecialAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 private Context mContext;
 private int[] colors = new int[] { 0x30FF0000, 0x300000FF };

 public SpecialAdapter(Context c) {
  mContext = c;
 }

 public int getCount() {
  return 0;
 }

 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return null;
 }

 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return 0;
 }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  int colorPos = position % colors.length;
  convertView.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
  return convertView;
 }

}

Comment: public class ListViewA extends Activity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

  gridview.setAdapter(new SpecialAdapter(this));
 }

}

Comment: good point :) I don't see the grid. Do you mean that class does his work ? How can I see what's wrong I've not idea :(

Comment: I've tried hard to edit the post but the forum code tag block me :(

Comment: it's the same uffa ! http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?824910-Android-How-set-Alternate-Cell-Color-in-a-Grid&p=5050138#post5050138