# Easy way to make an ImageView that is underneath a GridView match the GridView's size exactly?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-gridview

My `ImageView` is displaying an image of a chess style board for a little game I'm making. It is covered by a `GridView` that displays the images of my pieces. I have it displaying underneath but it is not positioned properly. I want it to match exactly the edges of the `GridView` but don't know how. Is there some way to make the `GridView` a "parent" of the `ImageView` so then I could say "match_parent" in the XML for it's height and width and so on?

Here is a screen of how my app looks now. I want the ugly colored grid I made to line up with the `GridView` images so that the black squares around the edge of my pieces are centered in the squares of the board.

[image]

Here is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/textFieldFU"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="8"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
```

Here is the relevant part of my `MainActivity`:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ImageAdapter iA = new ImageAdapter(this);

    final ImageView board;
    board = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    board.setImageResource(R.drawable.board1);


    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(iA);
...
```

And here is the relevant parts of my `ImageAdapter` that I have which sets up the `GridView`:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public static int[] images = { R.drawable.rock2, R.drawable.paper2,
        R.drawable.scissors2, R.drawable.rock2, R.drawable.paper2,
...//This part goes on for a while...
...//On to the relevant part...
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView iv;
    if (convertView != null) {
        iv = (ImageView) convertView;
    } else {
        iv = new ImageView(context);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(60, 60));
        iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
        iv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    iv.setImageResource(images[position]);
    return iv;
}

public static int[] getImagesArray() {
    return images;
}

public void setImagesArray(int[] newImages) {
    images = newImages;
}
```

----------------EDIT, Added the alternative solution from answer below.--------------

I got rid of the `ImageView` entirely and just added this to my `getView` in the `ImageAdapter` class:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView iv;
    if (convertView != null) {
        iv = (ImageView) convertView;
    } else {
        iv = new ImageView(context);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(60, 60));
        iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
        iv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        if(position < 8 && position % 2 ==0){
            iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        }
        else if(position > 7 && position < 16 && position % 2 ==1){
            iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        }
        else if(position > 15 && position < 24 && position % 2 ==0){
            iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        }
        else if(position > 23 && position < 32 && position % 2 ==1){
            iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        }
        else if(position > 31 && position < 40 && position % 2 ==0){
            iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        }
        else if(position > 39 && position < 48 && position % 2 ==1){
            iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        }
        else if(position > 47 && position < 56 && position % 2 ==0){
            iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        }
        else if(position > 55 && position < 64 && position % 2 ==1){
            iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        }
        else
            iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
    iv.setImageResource(images[position]);
    return iv;
}
```

Here is how it looks now:

[image]

Comment: This answer also helped me, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062512/how-set-alternate-cell-color-in-a-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the layout of the base element of your gridview.
An imageView with a custom background seems to be what you need.
You will have to check in getview in which row you are in order to know which background color to use.

Comment: That sounds promising, I'll check in to it now.

Comment: You were right, this is a much better idea than what I was doing. I'll post the solution up top.

Comment: Glad to hear it. It gives the additional benefit of getting rid of a layer. Avoiding as much as possible to pile-up layers is a good idea since it costs a lot of resources (the system has to draw all these successive layers, even if they are not visible.