# How to add colour to each cell of Grid view in Android?

Tags: android, gridview

Am developing a calculator in Android. I placed all the numbers and arithmetic operators in a grid view. The following is the xml code of the grid view :

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="270dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:columnWidth="20dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="50dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="20dp" >
</GridView>
```

I need to give colours to each cell of the grid view. Is it possible to do that ? If yes, how ?

Comment: Check this [Change Color of cell of grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315714/change-color-of-cell-of-grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u need to set an adapter .. check below link

```
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply searching in stackOverflow got a link [How set Alternate Cell Color in a Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062512/how-set-alternate-cell-color-in-a-grid). An accepted ans. was present , but the code works for **to set Alternate Cell Color** More possibilities are ter to solve your problem.